# Why can't a user see a specific directory in public folder in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, public-folders

I have added permissions for a client user to access specific public folder (it is folder that only has contact info) in Exchange Server 2010 SP3 using public folder management console.

When checking on the client's outlook (2013) this folder is not there under the normal public folders.

What do I still need to do for it to display?

Here is an image of what the end result would be in outlook:

[image: Contacts folder]

This is currently set up on a different user profile and I might need to remove this profile later on.

A link or simple step guide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any other Windows folder, ensure the user has permissions to list directory contents of the parent folder as well as the read permissions of the folder itself.

Also, keep in mind adding a user to a group often requires a log off (and back on) for the permissions to take effect.

After that, check and double-check the permissions, even the obvious.

Comment: The folder setup was done long ago by a previous technician and he cannot remember exactly what he did, however he does claim that there is steps to follow within the user's outlook to finalize the process. Pity he is actually too busy to do it himself. Gave +1 because this is always good advice, even though it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: After continuously checking permissions and fiddling around I realized that the public folder management console does not allow you to select the parent folder from the folder tree and automatically selects the first folder within the selected parent. Thus the parent folder never got permissions. Could you please add to your answer that permissions only get set on right window objects?